# Etale topology on the projective line

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X=\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^1$. I am trying to get a better handle on an etale topology on $X$.

I know that every open immersion is etale, and so open subsets of $X$ in the Zariski topology should also be open subsets in the etale topology.

What are some examples of open subsets on $X$ in the etale topology which are not open in the Zariski topology?

Comment: Etale cover of open subsets are the "open subsets" in the etale topology. So for example the maps $f_n:\mathbb{G}_m\to\mathbb{P}^1$ such that $z\mapsto [z^n:1]$ are etale (if $n\neq 0$) but not a Zariski open subset (if $n\neq\pm 1$).